# Guard fails on Windows 7 with Runtime Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, guard

Running

```
$bundle exec guard
```

with

```
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 3.2.11
Guard version 1.6.1
```

fails on Windows 7 64bit, for me with:

```
17:49:03 - INFO - Guard uses Notifu to send notifications.
17:49:03 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pry-0.9.11.3-x86-mingw32/lib/pry/command_set
.rb:216:in `alias_command': Command: `help` not found (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard/interacto
r.rb:135:in `block in create_command_aliases'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard/interacto
r.rb:134:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard/interacto
r.rb:134:in `create_command_aliases'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard/interacto
r.rb:95:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard.rb:161:in
 `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard.rb:161:in
 `setup_interactor'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard.rb:82:in
`setup'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard.rb:183:in
 `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/lib/guard/cli.rb:11
0:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27
:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor.rb:275:in
`dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:42
5:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.6.1/bin/guard:6:in `<to
p (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/guard:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

Do I need to start notifu in a specific way? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

RKing has [filed an issue at Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/394) and linked your question to it. It looks like this is either a problem with the latest Pry or Guard doesn't use the Pry API right.

Two things comes to mind to work around the issue:

1. Disable the interactor

   Since Pry is only used in the interactor, you can diable it when starting Guard and you should have the Guard plugins working at least:

   `$ bundle exec guard -i`
2. Find the last working Pry version

   I think you should get it running with an older version of Pry, the question is which version has introduced the incompatibility. You can use a fixed Pry version by specify the version in your `Gemfile` and run bundler:

   In your `Gemfile`:

   `gem 'pry', '0.9.11.2'`

   Then run bundler in the console:

   `$ bundle update`

   If it still doesn't work, just use a lower version. Please try `0.9.11.2`, `0.9.11.1`, `0.9.11` and `0.9.10`.

   If you have found a working version, please report it to the linked Guard issue at GitHub.

Comment: Just try `0.9.10`, if it doesn't work on `0.9.11.3` it won't work on any of the `0.9.11.x` line

Comment: @wolle Please try with Pry `0.9.11.4`, should be fixed now.